# spark 1.3 read and write to hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I want to read and write from hbase using spark 1.3 and cloudera CDH-5.4.7. I was using [spark-hbase-connector](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector). 
I start my spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --jars hbase-client-1.0.3.jar scalatest_2.10-2.2.4.jar hbase-common-1.0.3.jar spark-hbase-connector_2.10-1.0.3.jar hbase-server-1.0.3.jar
```

When I run this import:

```
import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._
```

I got an error. What is the best way to read and write from hbase using spark 1.3? 
Thank you

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: in the  `import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._` even i add the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below ?

run : spark-shell --jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-spark.jar

for code refer to the below link

https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/HBaseBulkGetExample.scala

Comment: i change it to my version `spark-submit --master yarn-client 
 --driver-class-path /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar  
 --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
 --class com.cloudera.spark.hbase.example.HBaseBulkPutExample spark_hbase-0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar `  but it doesn't work

Comment: First you need to build the jar using the code I provided, it is not available by default.
spark_hbase-0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar is the jar I created using the code.

Comment: i'm runing with spark-shell line by line because i dont have sbt (network security problem)

Comment: then you can open the spark-shell using the below command :

spark-shell --driver-class-path /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hbase/li‌​b/htrace-core-3.1.0-‌​incubating.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.‌​7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/li‌​b/hbase/lib/htrace-c‌​ore-3.1.0-incubating‌​.jar

Then you should have required jars in classpath and you would be able to access hbase data. Use my code as a reference.

Comment: i got an error when im importing `import com.cloudera.spark.hbase.HBaseContext`